# how to continue execution after sys.exit() command

Tags: python

Here i'm reading and comparing values from the two logs using 'for' loop.Problem is i'm not able to continue to next TC after sys.exit command. Let me know if required more clarification

```
f = open('/tmp/ftplog', 'r')
    for line in f:
        m = re.findall("5\d+", line)
        #print m
        fd = open('/tmp/tellog', 'r')
        for line in fd:
            n = re.findall(r"5\d+", line)
            #print n
            if  m == n:                 
             print "passed"

            sys.exit()  

####TC-02####

def tc02(ipadrr,login,password,ftpipaddr,ftplogin,ftppassword,ftpfilename):

    try:    

                telconn2 = pexpect.spawn(ipadrr)
```

Comment: short answer: you can't

Comment: `sys.exit()` should be indented with the `print` line above it (As a part of `if`). In python indentation is very important

Comment: use 'return' to come out of the nested nested loops.

Comment: @RedBaron i already tried with the way you told but not helps for me..

Comment: What is it that you actually want to achieve? Why are you using sys.exit() in the first place?

Comment: @lkke,this is last part of my 1st script after configuration.Here i just mentioned last section only where i want to continue my script after the loop.

Comment: @abhi: You probably want `break` then, rather than `sys.exit()`. That will break out of the inner loop. If you want to break out of both, you will need to set some kind of flag before `break`ing, so that the outer loop can detect this and `break`. Putting the whole first part in a function and then `returning` is probably even more appropriate though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
print "passed"

return ####instead of sys.exit use return
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add hooks that will be executed on exit using `atexit`. http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html?highlight=atexit#atexit

However, needing to do this in a simple script is usually a sign your logic is wrong. Do you really need to exit? Could you throw an exception instead? `break`? `return`? For example, try having the logic in a function, the function `return`ing when it is done, and some code that calls it and does something with the returned result.

Answer (score 4):

`sys.exit` *actually* throws a `SystemExit` exception, which you can catch, but you really *shouldn't*. Restructure your program so you don't have to.

Comment: Why shouldn't you catch it?  Some libraries (`argparse` comes to mind) throw it, and you don't always want to rewrite the library.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp When the source of `system.exit()` is... you, and it's a very simple does-one-thing script, needing to catch it is a sign that your program structure is bad.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this **if it's really needed** is to call the same script but with different parameters in a subprocess just before you exit it like this:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("exec your_script.py -parameters parameter", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Then you can add some checks for a specific parameter that you will provide and execute only this part of your code (e.g. the `tc02()` function that you need).

Just keep in mind that once you call the script as a subprocess, you won't be able to stop it from the console with Ctr+C, since this will kill the parent process, but not the child processes. In order to kill everything you need to call a method like this:

```
p.kill()
```